# Xcode error "fix-it" inserts suggestion wrong

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I recently updated Xcode to 6.3 and because of Swift 1.2 I got a view errors, which are really easy to fix.
Here comes Xcode's build-in feature to "fix" these automatically.

But since Xcode 6.1 beta this doesn't work properly (in Xcode 5 it worked perfectly)

for example it converts (unfortunately I can't post images):

```
let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
```

to

```
let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]as!s NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
```

instead of

```
let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as! NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
```

I didn't find anything online. Does anybody has the same problem? B.t.w it's not only a Problem in Xcode 6.3 beta, it occurs in any 6.X version

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to be a bug in Xcode 6.x report the bug: http://bugreporter.apple.com

That is the best way to get it fixed.